# InfiniteRepeatable in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

```kotlin
val value by transition.animateValue(
    initialValue = 0,
    targetValue = 10,
    typeConverter = Int.VectorConverter,
    animationSpec = infiniteRepeatable(
        animation = tween(durationMillis = 10000, easing = LinearEasing),
        repeatMode = RepeatMode.Restart
    )
)
```

for example, I think the variable value will increase from 0 to 10 in 10 seconds. But in my app, the animation seems faster than I suppose. Actually, the animation will repeat 2 times in 10 seconds, which means you have to set durationMillis to 20000 to achieve the supposed result.
Could someone please explain this, is it just a feature not an awkward design?

.....................